# How set CSS in All Browser Compatiblity?

Tags: html, css

How do I set CSS only for IE 7, 8 and 9?

```
.pager .pages { margin:4px 0px 0 0; float:right; }
```

The above class is not displayed in IE 7 and 8. So the design is not properly displayed.

Comment: When you say 'not displayed properly' .. How *is* it displayed?

Comment: Hello, i have got my answer and its proper working in My site. So, Please don't hesitate if you have concern then let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Naitik try following css.

```
For IE7:

    @media screen\9 {
    .pager .pages {
     margin:4px 0px 0 0; 
     float:right; 
    }
    }

    For IE8:

    @media \0screen{
   .pager .pages {
    {
    margin:4px 0px 0 0;
    float:right;
    }
    }

    For IE9:

    @media all and (min-width:0) {
    .pager .pages {
     margin:4px 0px 0 0; 
     float:right; ;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Jimmy, I have use your code and its working fine .Thanks

Comment: Omg.. and she accepted it too. Somewhere in the world a fairy died in agony because of you :(

Comment: who died because of me , Damien Overeem?

Comment: @Jimmy - the general jist of their agony is that these hacks have a tendency to backfire on you when 5 years from now all of these browsers are a tiny % of users and the hack happens to trip a new browser that is a big % of users. Now your "fix" of something small has broken something big. Best do the `<!--[if gt IE7]><![endif]-->` stuff. No sense in using a hack when a real solution exists. See Damien Overeem's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Put your css in a seperate .css file and add this to the end of your `<head>`

```
<!--[if gt IE7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

More info about conditional loading of css files here: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Answer (score 0):

All I can assume right now is that your seeing a default `body` margin/padding. Add this to your CSS and see if it makes a difference:

```
html,body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this.

```
.ie7 .pager .pages { //your style here }
.ie8 .pager .pages { //your style here }
.ie9 .pager .pages { //your style here }
```

for crossbrowsing as well.

Comment: What the hell is your answer?

Comment: where do those `.ieX` classes come from, then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919480/html5boilerplate-ie-conditional-not-working/10919615#10919615 or https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.0.1/doc/html.md#conditional-html-classes